# Midnight time issue

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am having problem detecting if the shop is still open or closed after midnight.

On Tuesday (`$weekday = 2`), shop open from 6 PM to 1:30 AM (after midnight)

Assume current time is 01:05 AM

```
    $weekday = 2;

    //Convert current time to minutes (01:05)
    $currentTime = ($weekday - 1) * 1440 + "01" * 60 + "05";

    //Current Week Day

    $shopOpenTime = "18:00";
    $shopCloseTime = "01:30";

    $open = explode(':', $shopOpenTime);
    $close = explode(':', $shopCloseTime);

    //Convert to Minutes;
    $MinutesOpen = (($weekday - 1) * 1440) + ($open[0] * 60 + $open[1]);
    $MinutesClose = (($weekday - 1) * 1440) + ($close[0] * 60 + $close[1]);
    if ($MinutesClose < $MinutesOpen)
        $MinutesClose += 60 * 24;


    if (($currentTime >= $MinutesOpen) && ($currentTime < $MinutesClose)) {
        echo "Shop Is Open";
    }  else { 
       echo "Shop Is Close";
     }
```

What is the solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly this entire chunk of code should be re-written.  The logic is doomed because your $weekday parameter is comparing the same day for $currentTime as $minutesOpen.  You added 24 hours to $minutesClose to push it to (technically Wed), now that comparison is correct.  It says Closed because you haven't moved $currentTime up 24 hours into wed.

So if you were to just read this in english you're comparing 1:30am on Tuesday (which is right after monday night) against 6:30 pm on Tuesday, and this fails  (this is because of the $weekday parameter is set to tuesday in the $currentTime).

Without seeing how you populate your $weekday parameter, I'm guessing that when you actually run this code being poplated with say the date() function, at 12:01 (on tuesday) it's going to increment to wed, then you're code will be populating open and close time with wed's hours, which is going to be off too.

I'm sorry I know this isn't a solution saying to re-write the entire logic, but it's going to be massively flawed in a production environment.

If you just want to make it work, staying with the mindset/context of 'tuesday' you have to reflect current time in tuesday's sense, and thats with 25:05 meaning 1:05 on wed, and not 01:05 tuesday for the second time.  That keeps the context correct and it works.

```
   $currentTime = ($weekday - 1) * 1440 + "25" * 60 + "05";
```

Comment: Ahh, I understand what you trying to say.. You have explained my logic very well. You did not say what the proper solution should be? Do you mean your last sentence is proper solution? ... The solution I am looking for that some day (day of the week) will have different open/close time. For example: Shop Company-A (Mon 18:00 to 23:30, Tues 11:00 to 22:00, Fri 13:00 to 01:00 (after midnight).... Should the minutes (INT) should be stored in the database or use TIME field type?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the current time to the opening period that **will** begin on the current time's day. But the shop is currently open due to an opening period that started yesterday. Just compare with yesterday's period also:

```
if ((($currentTime >= $MinutesOpen - 1440) && ($currentTime < $MinutesClose - 1440)) || (($currentTime >= $MinutesOpen) && ($currentTime < $MinutesClose))) {
```

But beware, this works only, if the shop opens / closes every day at the same time.

Comment: Everyday, shop opens / closes times could be different. eg: Mon 18:00 to 23:30, Tues 11:00 to 22:00, Fri 13:00 to 01:00 (after midnight). so what the solution to that?